# Can I implement Elmah like functionality now in an ASP.Net Azure application without the need for Elmah?

Tags: asp.net, azure, logging, asp.net-web-api, elmah

I would like to implement logging but would prefer just to use the Microsoft Stack. With all of the changes to diagnostics I find it difficult to keep up.

Can anyone tell me if they have removed Elmah and been able to replace it with the Microsoft Stack of diagnostics.  Note my application is an ASP.NET Web API Azure worker role Web application.

Comment: I would propably go with diagnostics logs as well. Browsing through the logs pretty much suck, but different third party tools helping you with that can be found through a simple google search.

Comment: I'm curious. Why don't you want to use ELMAH?

Comment: If I am using Azure and can get the same functionality with all MSoft would that not be easier?

Comment: You can get the error log, but not the nice browsing capabilities of ELMAH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use the diagnostics code for Windows Azure? It's super easy to add and the portal is great for viewing and analyzing logs:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

Comment: Hi Cris, This is what I was thinking to use but I would like to know if that offers me all that Elmah does. For instance would I be able to see stack traces if my application gives me a 500 error?

Comment: Yes! It will catch all errors and log them automatically. Then you can either stream or download the logs and analyze them. It can't get easier than this.

Comment: @SamanthaJ, if you are happy with this answer, could you please mark it as answered? thanks